# error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.3.1

Tags: eclipse, opencv, g++, ubuntu-14.04

A bit confused. I set up all required lib paths and still have `loading shared libraries error`.
From the  terminal when I type

```
>>pkg-config --libs opencv

-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudaobjdetect -lopencv_cudastereo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_cudafeatures2d -lopencv_superres -lopencv_cudacodec -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_cudaoptflow -lopencv_cudalegacy -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_cudawarping -lopencv_cudaimgproc -lopencv_cudafilters -lopencv_video -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_core -lopencv_cudev
```

Inside the file

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
```

I have /usr/local/lib

Then in Eclipse, I set up all include and lib paths as shown in the attached images.
[image] 
[image]

Then build the project has no error.
But when I debug, the error is

```
error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I need to type  sudo ldconfig at terminal

Comment: If you've resolved the problem then please answer your own question and accept the answer, so the question doesn't remain open.

Answer (score 1):

As batuman posted on Feb 2 at 10:10, run at terminal:
 sudo ldconfig 
Verified 9 Sept 2016, Ubuntu 16.04.1, Eclipse Luna and Opencv 3.1